# flutter sqflite DatabaseException no such table

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm trying to use sqflite here but I keep getting this error when I try to insert values there is no such table but I want to create a table

```
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(no such table: usernotes (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO usernotes (id, title, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?)) sql 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO usernotes (id, title, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' args [2021-03-05 20:44:59.369377, a new note, what should i do]})
```

here is my database helper class and the controller

```
import 'package:mynotes/models/note_model.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

class DBHelper {
  static sql.Database _database;

  static Future<void> init() async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      var databasePath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
      String _path = path.join(databasePath, 'notes.db');
      _database = await sql.openDatabase(_path, version: 1, onCreate: onCreate);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  static Future onCreate(sql.Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE usernotes(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,title TEXT,content TEXT)');
  }

  static Future insert(String table, NoteModel noteModel) async =>
      await _database.insert(table, noteModel.toMap(),
          conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
}
```

and here

```
import 'package:mynotes/helper/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/models/note_model.dart';

class NoteController with ChangeNotifier {
  List<NoteModel> _notes = [];
  List<NoteModel> get notes => _notes;

  Future<void> addToNote(String title, String content) async {
    try {
      await DBHelper.init();
      final newNote = NoteModel(
        id: DateTime.now().toString(),
        title: title,
        content: content,
      );
      _notes.add(newNote);
      notifyListeners();
      DBHelper.insert(
          'usernotes',
          NoteModel(
              id: newNote.id, title: newNote.title, content: newNote.content));
      notifyListeners();
      print(notes);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }}
```

so what is the problem here? I tried to run other project with same functions and this error didn't show

Comment: Got same problem here, I assume it is db version conflict things. but not sure

Answer (score 0):

try to switch

```
static Future<void> init() async {
if (_database != null) {
  return;
}

try {
  var databasePath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
  String _path = path.join(databasePath, 'notes.db');
  _database = await sql.openDatabase(_path, version: 1, onCreate: onCreate);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}}
```

to

```
static Future<Database> init() async {
if (_database != null) return _database;

try {
  var databasePath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
  String _path = path.join(databasePath, 'notes.db');
  _database = await sql.openDatabase(_path, version: 1, onCreate: onCreate);
  return _database;
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}}
```

because you need to return database here. Next in last segment you need to replace `await DBHelper.init();` to `db = await DBHelper.init();` and finally `DBHelper.insert(...` to `db.insert(...`

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately it gives me the same error

Comment: Tomorrow i will change my answer and provide you with code that i use for sqflite. If you still have the problem feel free come back here and use my solution.

Comment: Forgot to tell you that you are creating database `notes` and quering `usernotes`. So change it to be equal.

Comment: I solved it I just had to put this line Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add this line before opening the database

```
Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

and use this path

Answer (score 0):

Every time you have modified your database, you need to uninstall the app and **reinstall** it (or try to increase the schema version in your database).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using db.batch(), at the events onCreate and onUpgrade of the openDatabase, ensure that you commit your changes to persist them to the disk.

```
  onCreate: (db, version) async {

    final batch = db.batch();
        batch.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $myTable (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            name TEXT NOT NULL
          );  
        ''');
    await batch.commit(); // <----
  }, version: version,
```